# Php sum elements array into another array

Tags: php

Good morning,

when I create a new array with the sums of the previous one I would like to rename the fields of the new arrray.

To better understand: if in the first array I have imp01, in the new array I would like to be able to have the sum with the new name impTot01.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$array01 = array();
$array02 = array();
 
    $i = 0;

    $array01[$i]['IMP01'] = 7500;
    $array01[$i]['IMP02'] = 1800;
    $array01[$i]['IMP03'] = 1400;
    
    $i = 1;
    $array01[$i]['IMP01'] = 12500;
    $array01[$i]['IMP02'] = 21700;
    $array01[$i]['IMP03'] = 35250;
    
    $i = 2;
    $array01[$i]['IMP01'] = 52000;
    $array01[$i]['IMP02'] = 45000;
    $array01[$i]['IMP03'] = 33654;
 
    $array02 = array();

    foreach ($array01 as $k=>$subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
            isset($array02[$id]) || $array02[$id] = 0;
            $array02[$id]+=$value;
        }
    }      print_r($array02); exit;
?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First sum</th>
                <th>Second sum</th>
                <th>Third sum</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php if (count($array02) > 0){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array02['IMP01']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $array02['IMP02']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $array02['IMP03']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How about `$id = str_replace("IMP", "impTot", $id);` above the `$array02[$id]+=$value;` line?

Comment: `foreach (array_keys($array01[0]) as $key) {
    $array02[str_replace("IMP", "impTot", $key)] = array_sum(array_column($array01, $key));
}`